# How do I stop random sleep/hibernation?

Tags: debian, suspend, hibernate, surface, hybrid-sleep

I am currently running Debian 12 on a Microsoft Surface Pro 2 with the 6.4.12-surface kernel from the [linux-surface project](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface). However, I have been experiencing the computer's screen turning off and the computer locking for extended periods every 10 seconds. This also occurs on the default Debian kernel, as well as with Fedora Workstation 38. I have temporarily fixed the problem by completely disabling suspension of the system through `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`, but since this is a tablet that I would like to suspend at times, I want to fix the core issue at hand that causes this issue. What should I look at first, and what steps should I take to solve this problem?

Comment: Would `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` help?

Comment: @waltinator What should I be looking for that would cause this kind of behavior? Should I unmask the targets in order to observe this?

Comment: That command shows you the last 5 minutes of logs. If the software does the "off and lock", it will be logged.

Comment: Read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424 (the syslog stansard) Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog (an explanation) Read `man journalctl` to see your system logs.

Comment: I would check the log. Possible causes: overheating (why drivers may not be optimized, or why the system read wrongly the temperature or the temperature limits). Battery: the system may think you have empty batteries (wrong reading of data). Misinterpreting some hardware signals, etc. Log and `dmesg` command (so kernel logs) may give you some hints.